# while loop in socket io

Tags: python, socket.io, client, python-socketio

> hii i am trying to bulid client with socketio python.
> how can i break the loop when I catch an event

```
def login():
index = 0
while index == 0:
    username = input("please enter your username\n")
    password = input("please enter your password\n")
    sio.emit('send user name and password', {"username": username, "password": password})

    @sio.on('wrong username')
    def print_message():
        print("this username is not exist")

    @sio.on('wrong password')
    def print_message():
        print("your password is wrong please try again")

    @sio.on('connected')
    def print_message():
        global index
        index = 1
        print("LOGIN OK")

    sio.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put those functions in a loop. They catch their assigned event automatically:

```
def login():
    index = 0
    username = input("please enter your username\n")
    password = input("please enter your password\n")
    sio.emit('send user name and password', {"username": username, "password": password})

@sio.on('wrong username')
def print_message():
    print("this username is not exist")

@sio.on('wrong password')
def print_message():
    print("your password is wrong please try again")

@sio.on('connected')
def print_message():
    global index
    index = 1
    print("LOGIN OK")

   # sio.sleep(2)
```

Comment: but i want the funcation to ask again for username and password if the user is not exist or the password is worng

Answer (score 0):

Socket.IO is asynchronous, you don't put the event handler inside a while-loop. If you need synchronize you main thread with events you receive, you can use an `Event` object. Something like this:

```py
login_ok = None
event = threading.Event()

@sio.on('wrong username')
def print_message():
    print("this username is not exist")
    login_ok = False
    event.set()

@sio.on('wrong password')
def print_message():
    print("your password is wrong please try again")
    login_ok = False
    event.set()

@sio.on('connected')
def print_message():
    global index
    index = 1
    print("LOGIN OK")
    login_ok = True
    event.set()

def login():
    index = 0
    while index == 0:
        username = input("please enter your username\n")
        password = input("please enter your password\n")
        sio.emit('send user name and password', {"username": username, "password": password})

        event.wait()
        event.clear()
        if login_ok:
            break
```

Another option that you may want to consider, assuming you have also writing the server, is using the ACK feature of Socket.IO. Instead of responding to the login with a separate event, you can set the ACK response to the login result. Then you don't have to handle any events in the client, and can just get the result of the login from the event response. This is an example:

```py
def login():
    index = 0
    while index == 0:
        username = input("please enter your username\n")
        password = input("please enter your password\n")
        response = sio.call('send user name and password', {"username": username, "password": password})
        if response['login_ok']:
            break
        print(response['error'])
```

For this second option to work your server will have to be modified to send a dictionary with `login_ok` and `error` as a response to the login event.